# php intermittent undefined from $_get URL

Tags: php, get, http-status-code-404, undefined

I have a PHP page (teamlist.php) containing a list of teams, each of which link to a question page about that team. The HTML is:

```
./questions.php?team=wonderboys
```

The questions page uses the team variable to populate a hidden field called team name.

9 out of 10 times the teamlist.php page hands over correctly to questions.php.

Occasionally, the page crashes and returns a 404 error "404 Not Found".

The resource requested could not be found on this server!"

The questions.php page looks like this:

```
<?php
$team= ($_GET['team']);
?>
<html>
the html page
</html>
```

What error checking do I need to perform / be looking for to prevent this error from happening?

Thanks
Mathew

Comment: What does it say in the location bar of your browser when you get the 404. For a 404 unless you are checking and outputting the 404 response yourself then you are never getting to the questions.php

Comment: Seems a server issue, can you show us a part of the access/error logs?

Comment: Is it possible that requests are coming in to ./questions.php instead of ./questions.php?team=teamname ?

Comment: the url it 404's to is: http://mysite.com/teams/undefined - where teams is the directory that the project sits in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably stems from using relative url paths. Switch the links over to use site absolute paths (beginning with a /).

Assuming questions.php is in the site root (i.e. `http://www.mysite.com/questions.php=Wonderboys` is a valid url)
the url should be `/questions.php=wonderboys`